# How SharePoint Timer Service 'OWSTimer' Works?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

In our application, we need to build something similar to SharePoint timer service. This service needs to be installed on all web servers in a farm. A job can be scheduled to be run immidiately, daily, weekly or monthly on any or all web servers of the farm. Jobs configuration and schedule is stored in database (MS SQL 2008).

How SharePoint timer service executes these jobs exactly at the scheduled times?

- Does it get notified by SQL Server? (Notification services not available in SQl Express)
- Does it poll SQL Server after specific intervals to find if any job needs execution? (Does not guarantee precision.)
- Or what?

Comment: If it is the same, why not use a SPJobDefinition as the base to trigger your custom timer jobs. Make the sharepoint job run every min or so.

Comment: @djeeg. We do not use SharePoint framework. It will be installed on simple ASP.NET web servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use an existing framework

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartz.net